# Create a while loop in workflow in sharepoint 2010 designer

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-foundation

I want to build while loop in sharepoint 2010
ex :- 
I want to build the while loop in workflow for my recurring tasks
Thankyou

Answer (score 1):

In order to work with While loop in SharePoint designer workflow you can refer to this link [Create while loop in SharePoint Designer 2010](https://brianscodingexamples.wordpress.com/2013/05/09/create-while-loop-within-workflow-in-sharepoint-designer-2010/).

Also you can specify your requirement in little dept so that answer can be up to the question.

Please have a look to the link and let me know whether it helped you or not.

Thanks

Comment: Thankyou for your help.But I couldn't make much our of it as I am pretty new to this software. What I want is to send email for the recurring task and for that I need my workflow to work repeatedly.

Comment: Blocked... Brians coding examples distract me from my work...

Answer (score -1):

You can have a IF-Else condition in your workflow. There is no specific while loop in 2010 designer workflows. Can you please elaborate your requirement.

Comment: Thankyou for your help.But I couldn't make much our of it as I am pretty new to this software. What I want is to send email for the recurring task and for that I need my workflow to work repeatedly.

Comment: So it is something where you will be sending emails to some user whenever there is a change in the list items. You can easily do it using a SharePoint Designer workflow, create a workflow for that particular list on item modification. In the ribbon at top of the page you will have a Action dropdown, there you can find all the list of actions you can carry out like sending emails, creating conditions etc. There are many tutorials available on net for sharepoint designer. please go through one and it will be clear.

Comment: That's fine. My need is to send the email notification for recurring task again based on new start date and end date . And this loop will continue based on the number of times the client wants the same task to recur.

Comment: so whenever there is new start date that means item has been modified, so you can have the workflow configured to run each time the item has been modified.

Comment: This was the first thing I tried,it behaves like any other workflow and stops after executing once . Any other suggestions ?

Comment: Are you sure you have checked the option of Workflow to trigger on modification of item and not just on creation of item

Comment: yes !! I tried it once again !